# fullcalendar eventClick .modal("show") not opening modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

Using Porto theme that uses Bootstrap and am able to add new events but trying to get so can edit the event by clicking on, I can getthe id, title, etc... but the modal won't open.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    //alert('Event id: ' + calEvent.id);    
    //alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
    //alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
    //alert('View: ' + view.name);      
    $('#calendarmodalForm').modal("show");
},
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

If the show option isn't working, why not try the toggle option instead?

```
$('#calendarmodalForm').modal("toggle");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It didn't work but did notice it messing with the page scroll bar. [screencast link](http://screencast.com/t/daLvu5WUev)